# How do I set the pixels per inch for an exported JPEG image in a Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a Cocoa Mac image editing app which lets users export JPEG images. I'm currently using the following code to export these images as JPEG files:

```
//this is user specified
NSInteger resolution;

NSImage* savedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(600, 600)];
[savedImage lockFocus];
//draw here 
[savedImage unlockFocus];

NSBitmapImageRep* savedImageBitmapRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[savedImage TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression:NSTIFFCompressionNone factor:1.0]];

NSDictionary* properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], NSImageCompressionFactor, nil];

//holds the jpeg file
NSData * imageData = nil;
imageData = [savedImageBitmapRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:properties];
```

However, I would like for the user to be able to provide the pixels per inch for this JPEG image (like you can in Photoshop's export options). What would I need to modify in the above code to adjust this value for the exported JPEG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it with the NSImage APIs but CGImage can by setting kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight/Width.

I also set kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality which I think is the same as NSImageCompressionFactor.

```
//this is user specified
NSInteger resolution = 100;

NSImage* savedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(600, 600)];
[savedImage lockFocus];
//draw here 
[savedImage unlockFocus];

NSBitmapImageRep* savedImageBitmapRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[savedImage TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression:NSTIFFCompressionNone factor:1.0]];

NSDictionary* properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality,
                            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:resolution], kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight,
                            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:resolution], kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth,
                            nil];

NSMutableData* imageData = [NSMutableData data];
CGImageDestinationRef imageDest =  CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef) imageData, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);
CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDest, [savedImageBitmapRep CGImage], (CFDictionaryRef) properties);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDest);

// Do something with imageData
if (![imageData writeToFile:[@"~/Desktop/test.jpg" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically:NO])
    NSLog(@"Failed to write imageData");
```

Comment: Great answer, can you also suggest how do I specify a color profile? For example adobe rgb/srgb etc.

Answer (score 3):

For `NSImage` or `NSImageRep` you do not set the resolution directly but set the size instead.
For size, numberOfPixels and resolution the following equation holds:

`size = numberOfPixels * 72.0 / resolution`

`size` is a length and is expressed in dots with the unit `inch/72`. 
(`size` and `resolution` are floats). You can see that for an image with dpi=72 size and numberOfPixels are numerally the same (but the meaning is very different).

After creating an `NSBitmapImageRep` the size with the desired resolution can be set:

```
NSBitmapImageRep* savedImageBitmapRep = . . . ; // create the new rep
NSSize newSize;
newSize.width = [savedImageBitmapRep pixelsWide] * 72.0 / resolution;  // x-resolution
newSize.height = [savedImageBitmapRep pixelsHigh] * 72.0 / resolution;  // y-resolution
[savedImageBitmapRep setSize:newSize];
// save the rep
```

Two remarks: do you really need the lockFocus / unlockFocus way? The preferred way to build a new NSBitmapImageRep is to use `NSGraphicsContext`. see : http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg74857.html

And: to use `TIFFRepresentation` for an `NSBitmapImageRep` is very time and space consuming. Since 10.6 another
way exists and costs nothing, because lockFocus and unlockFocus create an object of class `NSCGImageSnapshotRep` which under the hood is a CGImage. (In OS versions before 10.6 it was an `NSCachedImageRep`.) The following does it:

```
[anImage lockFocus];
// draw something
[anImage unlockFocus];
// now anImage contains an NSCGImageSnapshotRep
CGImageRef cg = [anImage CGImageForProposedRect:NULL context:nil hints:nil];
NSBitmapImageRep *newRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:cg];
// set the resolution
// here you may NSLog anImage, cg and newRep
// save the newRep
// release the newRep if needed
```